# Installed Python3, but it outputs error in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, python-3.x

I have installed python 3. But cmake .. shows an error:
`PYTHON3_INCLUDE_DIR detected at /usr/include/python3.2mu, but
  /usr/include/python3.2mu/Python.h does not seem to exist
Call Stack (most recent call first):`
usr/include/python3.2mu has only one file pyconfig.h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are calling cmake, I infer you are trying to build some Python C extensions.  You will also need to install the package [`python3-dev`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python3-dev&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) to make this work.